# PHP Tertiary statement in echo...? Syntax problems

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

Just having issues with the syntax for this, is it possible?

```
echo '<li><a href="' .$item->url. '" ' .($item->target != '') ? "target=$item->target" : "". '>' .$item->post_title. '</a></li>';
```

I'm not sure where I should concatenate and how to echo the if statement result.

Comment: You should probably specify clearer what your `condition`, `true-expression` and possible `false-expression` should be.

Comment: Point taken, it does look quite a jumble..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence can be ugly, especially in PHP where the rules for the `?:` operator don't match most other languages (it is left-associative in PHP, and right-associative ~everywhere else, though this is unlikely to be your problem since you only use the operator once here).

When in doubt, use parentheses to make your intent clear:

```
echo '<li><a href="' .$item->url. '" ' . (
    ($item->target != '')
    ? "target=$item->target"
    : ""
). '>' .$item->post_title. '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Also, I think they meant to leave out "target=". But a great answer +1.

Comment: That's possible.  I'm not going to make that assumption though.

Comment: I just re-read the question, scratch the first part of my comment. Woops.

Comment: Yep, the brackets were round the wrong bit of code but with a couple of minor adjustments it works. Thanks very much cdhowie and machino for answering.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use braces because the php would not recognize the end of tern. op.

```
echo '<li><a href="' .$item->url. '" ' . (
  ($item->target != '')
  ? "target=$item->target"
  : ("". '>' .$item->post_title. '</a></li>')
);
```